# Are FreeBSD binaries compatible with macOS?

Tags: freebsd, macos, binary, compatibility

Since FreeBSD and macOS (OS X) are very similar to each other, can programs written for FreeBSD run on macOS? And if a program can't, then would it be possible to make it work?

Comment: Is there a more specific _issue_ you are trying to solve? Note that both operating systems run on several different CPU architectures and that not even FreeBSD binaries run on FreeBSD if the architecture for which the binary was compiled is different from what's on the host.

Answer (score 1):

macOS use the [Mach-O](https://github.com/aidansteele/osx-abi-macho-file-format-reference) binary format and FreeBSD use the [ELF](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?elf(5)) binary format.

To answer your question: FreeBSD binaries are not compatible with macOS, but you can recompile a FreeBSD program (with probably some modifications) to make it run on macOS.